# How to store array values in to variable

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array and i want to store to a variable , how to do this

```
array(4) {["FirstName"]=> string(3) "abc" ["LastName"]=> string(5) "cvbcb" ["Email"]=> string(14) "sfsfd@afaf.com"}
```

Comment: Isn't the array already into a variable then?

Comment: which value you want to store.

Comment: `$myVar = array_values($your_array)`

Comment: how to fetch individual values from array

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourArray = array('FirstName' => 'abc', 'LastName' => 'cvbcb', 'Email' => 'sfsfd@afaf.com');
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have the array like this:

```
$arr = array('FirstName' => 'abc', 
             'LastName' => 'cvbcb', 
             'Email' => 'sfsfd@afaf.com'
            );
```

This is a single dimension array so you need to use the `index / key` with the array name for access and assign each item from the array. Here is the demo.

```
$firstName = $arr['FirstName']; // abc
$LastName = $arr['LastName']; // cvbcb
$Email = $arr['Email']; // sfsfd@afaf.com
```